# Is there a pythonic way to process tree-structured dict keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I'm looking for a pythonic idiom to turn a list of keys and a value into a dict with those keys nested.  For example:

```
dtree(["a", "b", "c"]) = 42
    or
dtree("a/b/c".split(sep='/')) = 42
```

would return the nested dict:

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": 42}}}
```

This could be used to turn a set of values with hierarchical keys into a tree:

```
dtree({
    "a/b/c": 10,
    "a/b/d": 20,
    "a/e": "foo",
    "a/f": False,
    "g": 30 })

would result in:

{   "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": 10,
            "d": 20 },
        "e": foo",
        "f": False },
    "g": 30 }
```

I could write some FORTRANish code to do the conversion using brute force and multiple loops and maybe `collections.defaultdict`, but it seems like a language with splits and joins and slices and comprehensions should have a primitive that turns a list of strings `["a","b","c"]` into nested dict keys `["a"]["b"]["c"]`.  What is the shortest way to do this without using `eval` on a dict expression string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm looking for a pythonic idiom to turn a list of keys and a value into a dict with those keys nested.

```
reduce(lambda v, k: {k: v}, reversed("a/b/c".split("/")), 42)
```

> This could be used to turn a set of values with hierarchical keys into a tree

```
def hdict(keys, value, sep="/"):
    return reduce(lambda v, k: {k: v}, reversed(keys.split(sep)), value)

def merge_dict(trg, src):
    for k, v in src.items():
        if k in trg:
            merge_dict(trg[k], v)
        else:
            trg[k] = v

def hdict_from_dict(src):
    result = {}
    for sub_hdict in map(lambda kv: hdict(*kv), src.items()):
        merge_dict(result, sub_hdict)
    return result

data = {
    "a/b/c": 10,
    "a/b/d": 20,
    "a/e": "foo",
    "a/f": False,
    "g": 30 }

print(hdict_from_dict(data))
```

#### Another overall solution using `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections

def recursive_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(recursive_dict)

def dtree(inp):
    result = recursive_dict()
    for keys, value in zip(map(lambda s: s.split("/"), inp), inp.values()):
        reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], keys[:-1], result)[keys[-1]] = value
    return result

import json
print(json.dumps(dtree({
    "a/b/c": 10,
    "a/b/d": 20,
    "a/e": "foo",
    "a/f": False,
    "g": 30 }), indent=4))
```

Comment: this is really cool answer! you made me google explanation for this and other similar python built-in functions: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php

Comment: Reversed could be changed into `[::-1]`, maybe?

Comment: @AmitGold There's no reason to. In fact `[::-1]` is less efficient because it has to build a new list, while `reversed` is only an iterator.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't actually know how `reversed` works, but it seems to me that `list`'s implementation would be more specific to the list itself and thus better than `reversed` which should handle an arbitary iterable... (I think)

Comment: @AmitGold No, `reversed` requires a *sequence* and simply calls `__getitem__` with the indices starting from the last, but it is lazy and requires only constant space. Using `[::-1]` will produce a new list which doubles the memory (at least for a while, until the other one is garbage collected).

Comment: @grepe - yes, a really cool answer!  Looking at the sequence [42, "c", "b", "a"] and the left-to-right triangle diagram in http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php makes it crystal clear, and leads to a forehead slap "Why didn't I think of that?"

Answer (score 0):

Or just for grins since `reduce` is the coolest thing since sliced bread, you could save one SLOC by using it twice :-)

```
def dmerge(x, y):
    result = x.copy()
    k = next(iter(y))
    if k in x:
        result[k] = dmerge(x[k], y[k])
    else:
        result.update(y)
    return result

def hdict(keys, value, sep="/"):
    return reduce(lambda v, k: {k: v}, reversed(keys.split(sep)), value)

def hdict_from_dict(src):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: dmerge(x, y), [hdict(k, v) for k, v in src.items()])

data = {
    "a/b/c": 10,
    "a/b/d": 20,
    "a/e": "foo",
    "a/f": False,
    "g": 30 }

print("flat:", data)
print("tree:", hdict_from_dict(data))
```

Comment: I had a similar prototype. In the end I disliked piping side-effects through `reduce` without really utilizing the returned value of the reduction function. Nevertheless, this is not the shortest version possible. You don't need to copy `x`. Just modify `x` and return it as result. It does not matter as you created the hdicts. Further, you can use the list comprehension to already unpack the mapping pair. This way you can pattern match `k` and `y[k]` in the reduction function. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mhoff/53be2c14195dbeb424722009da5d730b) for the condensed version. :)